# Replace Bcache Backing Device

Tags: bcache

Suppose I want to replace the crusty old HDD I'm using as a backing device with a new one.  Can I transfer my data to the new device without having to set up.an entirely new bcache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in theory because the new device should have the same UUID as the old one if you perform a block level copy.

Comment: Could I use a utility like Clonezilla for this?

Comment: @DanielStevenson, Likely but I would not know as I would just use dd, cat, or the like.